# Count of duplicates using group by function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below.

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | Full |  |
| 15 | BCD | CON |  |
| 19 | ABC | CON |  |
| 13 | ABC | FULL |  |
| 16 | XYZ | FULL |  |

I want to populate ID as below

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | Full | 2 |
| 15 | BCD | CON | 1 |
| 19 | ABC | CON | 1 |
| 13 | ABC | FULL | 2 |
| 16 | XYZ | FULL | 1 |

I want count column to be updated with number of records available for group by ( username, type)
basically want the  number of duplicate records for user_name||type in count

Answer (score 0):

Note that 'Full' is not the same as 'FULL', so that might have tripped you up. To achieve what you want, you can create an update statement like this, by basically counting the occurrences using a `GROUP BY` and using the correct where statement to get your counts.

Also try to avoid reserved names `TYPE` and `COUNT` as column names.

```sql
UPDATE MY_TABLE A SET COUNT = 
(
  SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM MY_TABLE B
  WHERE A.USER_NAME = B.USER_NAME
    AND LOWER(A.TYPE) = LOWER(B.TYPE)
  GROUP BY USER_NAME, LOWER(TYPE)
);
```

Take a look at this example:
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wthBl_fw)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement with the `COUNT` analytic function correlated on the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
MERGE INTO orders dst
USING (
  SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_name, UPPER(type)) AS cnt
  FROM   orders
) src
ON (src.ROWID = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Count = src.cnt;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders ( USER_ID, USER_NAME, Type, Count) AS
SELECT  1, 'ABC', 'Full', CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 15, 'BCD', 'CON',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 19, 'ABC', 'CON',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 'ABC', 'FULL', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 'XYZ', 'FULL', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE`, the table contains:

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | TYPE | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | Full | 2 |
| 15 | BCD | CON | 1 |
| 19 | ABC | CON | 1 |
| 13 | ABC | FULL | 2 |
| 16 | XYZ | FULL | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MyyO0-De)